# Copy constructor throws a std::bad_alloc, when it is called

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor

I am new c++ programmer. I want to create a Matrix class in c++ using dynamic programming. I had a problem with copy constructor. When I call operator + to use it for matrix-addition, the copy constructor throws a bad_alloc-Exception. The problem occurs in the copy-constructor, when i try to create a new dynamic memory, where i can copy my data:
matrix= new int [size];
I don 't understand why.
Here is the whole code: (only the cpp-file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.hpp"

Matrix::Matrix(int m, int n){
    mat_row=m;
    mat_col=n;
    matrix = new int[mat_row*mat_col];
    //initialization
    for(int i=0;i<mat_row*mat_col;i++){
       matrix[i]=0;
     }
 }

 //copy-Constructor
  Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& mat){
      int size=mat_row*mat_col;
      matrix= new int [size];
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
          matrix[i]=mat.matrix[i];
      }
    }

  Matrix::~Matrix(){
      if(matrix){
          delete [] matrix;
      }
  }


  //assigment operator
  Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& mat){
      std::cout<<"assignment-operator is used"<<std::endl;
      if(this!=&mat){
          int size=mat_row*mat_col;
          for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
             matrix[i]=mat.matrix[i];
          }
      }
      return *this; 
  }

  void Matrix::set(int m, int n, double value){
      if(matrix){
          matrix[m*mat_col+n]=value;
      }
  }

  double Matrix::get(int m, int n){
      return matrix[m*mat_col+n];
  }


 Matrix Matrix::operator+(Matrix mat){
 /*
    Matrix resultMatrix(mat_row, mat_col);
    for(int i=0;i<mat_row;i++){
        for( int j=0;j<mat_col;j++){
            resultMatrix->set(i,j,this->get(i,j)+mat.get(i,j));
         }
    }
    return *this;
  */
  }



    int main(){
        Matrix mat1(3,3);
        mat1.set(0,0,11);
        mat1.set(1,1,22);
        mat1.set(2,2,33);
        mat1.print();
        std::cout<<std::endl;   

       Matrix mat2(3,3);
       mat2=mat1;
       mat2.print();
       std::cout<<std::endl;
       mat2.set(0,1,55);
       mat2.set(1,1,110);
       mat2.set(2,2,220);
       mat2.print();

       mat1+mat2; //the problem occurs when this row will be executed
     }
```

Comment: Operator+ prototype should be `Matrix operator+ (const Matrix & left, const Matrix & right)`

Comment: No, it shouldn't in this case. In this case it should be `Matrix operator+ (const Matrix & mat)` because it is a member function. If the OP had included a friend function for operator+ then you're signature would be correct.

Comment: Why `new`? You should use a template and store the values right in the `Matrix` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that in your copy constructor mat_row and mat_col are not initialized. They should be getting set from the values that are in the object you are copying before you multiply them together to make size. If you don't do that first then the existing values are undefined and likely very large values, causing the new to fail.

```
//copy-Constructor
  Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& mat){
      mat_row = mat.mat_row;
      mat_col = mat.mat_col;
      int size=mat_row*mat_col;
      matrix= new int [size];
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
          matrix[i]=mat.matrix[i];
      }
    }
```

It looks like you have the exact same problem in you operator=() as well.

In the code where you indicate that your problem shows up you do not have an lvalue. You have `mat1+mat2;` so the result of that addition ends up being unused.

Also, your operator+() should be taking a const ref to the matrix and that is your actual issue. Passing by value like you currently are will cause a temporary copy which is created through the copy constructor.

Comment: I initialized them, but still habe the problem. There is a problem of segmentation fault. When mat1+ mat2 is executed, the coy-constructor will be called. Then the copy-constructor try to allocate a new memory portion dynamically. At that point occurs a segmentation fault

Comment: You get an exception on new when the allocation fails. This usually suggests that the size of the allocation is inappropriate. I just ran your code and it seems to work as long as you make the fix I suggested to both the copy constructor and to the assignment operator, like I suggested in the answer.

Comment: thank you very much. it works now::::)))). I passed the matrix by constant reference like you said. Then i  changed the methode get (i, j) to a constant methode. Now it works.But why the allocation failed, when we pass by value. Why the copy created by copy-constructor causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: because when you pass by value you make a temporary copy of the object which calls the copy constructor and that was not providing a valid size for the new. When you pass by reference you bypass the copy constructor.